# Increasing TPS63001 Under Voltage lockout from 1.8V to 2.5V for use with LiFePO4 cell

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, low-power, buck-boost, lifepo4

[image: TPS63001 Buck Boost converter circuit]

The Under Voltage Lockout threshold for this chip ranges from 1.5 V to 1.8 V. I want to use this with a LiFePO4 cell, whose minimum voltage is 2.5 V.

With reference to the datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63001.pdf), the VINA pin is responsible for monitoring the input voltage.

As such Will it be effective to connect a schottky diode with 800mV forward voltage dropt between VIN and VINA pins, to shutdown the chip when VIN reaches 2.5 V?

Any better ways to solve this? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Accordong the datasheet the quiescent current of VINA is just 40uA typical. You may even need 2 diodes to get enough voltage drop with that low current.

Another solution might be using a PNP transistor, which cuts off the supply to VINA when the battery voltage becomes too low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4NUBS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>